# Getting data from nested fields using mongoDB and php driver manager

Tags: php, mongodb

I have a document in the following format:

```
 "_id" : ObjectId("5c6f16d9b4a523195c007ecb"),
 "customerId" : "5c6dba6fb4a5231878007845",
 "products" : [
         {
                 "id" : "5c6c5b52dac9902ca917c98b",
                 "name" : "Black Starry Mug"
         }
]
```

What I am trying to do is retrieve the name from products.

```
<?php
$customerId = $_GET["customer-id"];
$cart = json_decode($_GET["cart"]);
$manager = new \MongoDB\Driver\Manager("mongodb://localhost:27017");
$filter  = ['customerId' => $customerId];
$options = [];
$query = new MongoDB\Driver\Query($filter , $options);
try {
    $result = $manager->executeQuery('GameMerchandise.cart', $query);
    $row = $result->toArray();
    foreach ($row as $item) {
        echo $item->products->name;
   }
}catch(MongoDB\Driver\Exception\Exception $e) {
    die("Error communicating with database: " . $e);
}
```

The problem comes from the echo part in the foreach loop. I have found information on how to do this with the legacy driver but nothing with the new one. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `products` part of your object is an array that you need to loop over as well. Try this:

```
foreach ($row as $item) {
    foreach ($item->products as $product) {
        echo $product->name;
    }
}
```

Comment: If I could give more than 1 vote I would. Thanks a million!